# select query not giving desired result

Tags: sql

I'm writing a select query, in the where condition i want to check a field value if it is null then ONLY i will other other field value. Please note the select is used in a cursor.

Original query:

---

```
SELECT ni.node_installation_id,ni.customer_node_id,ni.customer_id,c.brand_name_1,substr(nitr.name,1,instr(nitr.name, ' ')-1) as node_inst_type
    from node_installation ni , customer c , node_inst_type_release nitr
    where ni.customer_id = c.customer_id 
    and ni.node_inst_type_release_id = nitr.node_inst_type_release_id
    **and trunc(sysdate) - trunc(ni.arne_timestamp) >= 60** 
    and ni.no_of_collection_node_missed >= 4
    and c.customer_id =90;
```

Refer statement in bold , if ni.arne_timestamp is null the result also null. In this case i want to check for other condition like ni.arne_flag = 'I' and take those rows in select query. Hope I'm clear this time.

Comment: you are using here cartisian product in from clause use left joins instead

Comment: The root cause is because you are writing archaic SQL. If you use the ANSI92 (1992!) syntax, you may find the issue will mysteriously go away, or make itself clear.

Answer (score 1):

> if ni.arne_timestamp is null the result also null. In this case i want
>   to check for other condition like ni.arne_flag = 'I'

Add a check for `NULL` values within the `AND` predicate like so:

```
...
AND(ni.arne_timestamp IS NULL OR ni.arne_flag = 'I')
AND(ni.arne_timestamp IS NULL 
    OR 
    (trunc(sysdate) - trunc(ni.arne_timestamp)) >= 60 )
```

So your query, with the ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax after that should look like so:

```
SELECT 
  ni.node_installation_id,
  ni.customer_node_id,
  ni.customer_id,
  c.brand_name_1,
  substr(nitr.name, 1, instr(nitr.name, ' ') - 1) as node_inst_type
FROM node_installation ni 
INNER JOIN customer c ON ni.customer_id = c.customer_id 
INNER JOIN node_inst_type_release nitr 
        ON ni.node_inst_type_release_id = nitr.node_inst_type_release_id
WHERE (ni.arne_timestamp IS NULL OR ni.arne_flag = 'I')
  AND (ni.arne_timestamp IS NULL 
         OR 
       (trunc(sysdate) - trunc(ni.arne_timestamp)) >= 60 )
  AND ni.no_of_collection_node_missed >= 4
  AND c.customer_id = 90;
```